# Does a 3D model need to be UV unwrapped to be usable in XNA?

Tags: 3d, xna, xna-4.0

I'm looking at using one of two different models in an XNA application:

A) http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/maya-airbus-economy-class-interior/445732 
or
B) http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/fbx-real-time/613987

B has been UV unwrapped, while A hasn't. I'd prefer to use A, but I'm unsure if it could be handled by XNA or if XNA requires you to use unwrapped textures.

What limits/specifications does XNA have on the models it can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map textures on the model - then it has to be unwrapped and mapped, yes. Depending on how complicated the UV-mapping and/or the model is, you can choose to do it yourself and export it using a plugin for whatever modeling tool you use.

Note that an XNA model can have both textured and un-textured pieces as parts (but I have never seen any models that are partially unwrapped yet, perhaps the exporters don't do it?).

Ideally you'd get a final FBX that is broken up by [ModelMesh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198082)es that is already UV-mapped correctly. Your option B looks very nicely done, even going so far as to state that it is "real-time" which means polycount has been optimized for real time rendering.